# How to create a regular 5/2 star in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app, snapping

I need to create a regular 5/2 star in Sketch.
Like this:

[image]

I tried it, but Sketch can't draw simple geometry, it has a strange snapping.

You can see it in this video on youtube:
https://youtu.be/HPVo685hyxU

Comment: I'd rather not have to download a video from a random link, could you upload it to youtube so we can just stream it?

Comment: i published video on youtube https://youtu.be/HPVo685hyxU

Comment: I think you're trying to use Sketch for something it isn't meant to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Sketch doesn't snap to vector points, otherwise this would be easy. However, we can snap to the bounding box of an object and it is possible to abuse this to create a perfect star.

Create a five sided polygon and remove the vector points one by one and create vertical and horizontal guidelines for each point. Then use these guidelines to snap the cursor when drawing a star:

[image: star from polygon]

Comment: its very strange, but its a solution )

Answer (score 3):

Star is available in **Insert > Shape > Star**
Draw the star you can add the type of color you want and if you double click on it and you can change it from it's nodes. A simple vector work.
[image]
**Draw the star like you did in the video:**

[image]
**The Double click on it. It'll show you the nodes. Align then make anything from this star as you like:
[image]
**You can add/delete nodes too:**
[image]
**UPDATE**
 I am able to do that just by adjusting nodes.
[image]

Comment: its a not regular five-pointed star, please see video https://youtu.be/HPVo685hyxU

Comment: @ЕвгенийБалашов see my updated answer.

Comment: this way cannot give us the perpendicular sides — http://www.imghost.in/img/2016-11/22/s1yobvc1ovnutjpgus2mbh036.png

Comment: :(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((